# Find the value fluctuating in lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, pattern-matching, conditional

Suppose that I have the following lists of entries,

```
X1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
X2={2,4,6,1,10,12,3,16,18,20};
X3={4,8,12,5,20,24,6,24,20,30};
X4={5,10,16,3,30,30,6,25,25,40};
```

The entries of `X1` represent the values of a physical phenomenon of different points at time `t=1`. `X2` represents the values of the same values at time `t=2` and the same for `t=3` and `t=4`.

Now, I would like to find the position of the values that are fluctuating from time `t=1` to time `t=4`.

Of course, in practice my data are huge. These data are just arbitrary values.

Comment: by _fluctuating_ you mean?

Comment: I mean not increasing or decreasing constantly. Shown variational behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fluctuatingPos1 = Pick[Range @ Length @ #, 
   MatchQ[#, {___, a_, ___, b_, ___, c_, ___} /; a < b > c || a > b < c]& /@ #] & @
    Transpose[#]&; 
fluctuatingPos2 =  Flatten@Position[#, {___, a_, ___, b_, ___, c_, ___} /; 
        a < b > c || a > b < c, 1] & @ Transpose[#] &;
fluctuatingPos3 = Flatten @ Position[Unitize[Length[DeleteDuplicates[#]] -  1 & /@ 
  (Sign[Differences[#]] & /@ Transpose[#])], 1, 1] &;
fluctuatingPos4 = Flatten @ Position[(Boole @ Nor[OrderedQ[#], OrderedQ[Reverse@#]] &) /@ 
 Transpose[#], 1] &;

fluctuatingPos1[{X1, X2, X3, X4}]
```

> {4, 7}

```
Equal[fluctuatingPos1@#, fluctuatingPos2@#, fluctuatingPos3@#, 
  fluctuatingPos4@#] &@{X1, X2, X3, X4}
```

> True

```
SeedRandom[1]
Y = RandomInteger[10, {1000, 1000}];
{r1 = fluctuatingPos1[Y]; // AbsoluteTiming // First,
 r2 = fluctuatingPos2[Y]; // AbsoluteTiming // First,
 r3 = fluctuatingPos3[Y]; // AbsoluteTiming // First,
 r4 = fluctuatingPos4[Y]; // AbsoluteTiming // First}
```

> {0.747986, 0.755511, 0.031081, 0.009527}

```
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

> True

Comment: Thanks. It works for any lists.But could you explain the difference between these functions?

Comment: @MsenRezaee, I added timings for a large input list.

Comment: Great! It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

It sound like you want to fit a linear growth model and pick out those data sets that have high error variance. This can be done with `LinearModelFit`.

Here, I merge you data into a single matrix and add also a list `tlist` for the time points of your measurements.

```
X = Transpose[{X1, X2, X3, X4}];
tlist = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This computes fitted models for you data.

```
fit = LinearModelFit[Transpose[{tlist, #}], {t, 1}, t] &;
data = fit /@ X;
```

And this returns the estimated error variances. High values mean high fluctuation:

```
variances = #["EstimatedVariance"] & /@ data
```

> {0.1, 0.4, 0.75, 4.35, 3.75, 3.6, 4.5, 7.35, 4.5, 3.15544*10^-29}

So given a `threshold`, you can find the position of the data sets with higher variance as `threshold` with

```
threshold = 0.5
Flatten[Position[variances, _?(# > threshold &)]]
```

Comment: Very nice and professional!

Comment: Huh... professional? Thanks for the flowers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **high-pass filter**. It lets quick variations in the data pass through. This is what the four datasets look like when high-pass filtered:

```
ListLinePlot[HighpassFilter[#, 2] & /@ {X1, X2, X3, X4}]
```

[image: High-pass filtered datasets]

I have used a cutoff frequency of 2 here, you may want to adjust that according to your data.

To get some quantification, you could sum over the absolute values, for example:

```
N@Total[Abs@HighpassFilter[#, 2]] & /@ {X1, X2, X3, X4}
(* {0.477118, 19.1493, 37.1699, 49.6903} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be a bit late to this thread, but if you're just looking to test whether your list is monotonically increasing or decreasing, I think there's a much simpler way:

```
isMonotonic := Length@DeleteCases[
 DeleteDuplicates@Sign@Differences@#
 , 0] < 2 &

isMonotonic /@ {X1, X2, X3, X4}
{True, False, False, False}
```

Here, we're just using `Sign` to take the sign of the `Differences` of the given list, and checking whether both `1` and `-1` appear.